# Cannot find a way to prove functions correctly on pizza shop assignment

Tags: python, windows, function, jupyter-notebook, variable-assignment

```
drinks = []
wings = []
coupon = 0.1

def cost_calculator(p, drinks=None, wings=None, coupon=None):
        receipt = 0
        receipt = receipt + pizza_calc(pizzas)
    receipt = receipt + drinks_calc(drinks)
    receipt = receipt + wings_calc(wings)
    receipt = receipt*0.0625
    receipt = receipt*coupon
    receipt = receipt(receipt, 2)

def pizza_calc(pizzas):
    p = {[]:13}
    total += p[[]]
    for p in pizzas:
        if pepperoni in p:
            total += 1
        if mushroom in p:
            total += 0.5
        if olive in p:
            total += 0.5
        if anchovy in p:
            total += 2
        if ham in p:
            total += 1.5
    return(p)
        
def drinks_calc(drinks):
    d = 0
    total = 0
    for d in drinks:
        if d == "small":
            total += 2
        if d == "medium":
            total += 3
        if d == "large":
            total += 3.5
        if d == "tub":
            total += 3.75
    return(d)
        
def wings_calc(wings):
    w = 0
    total = 0
    for w in wings:
        if w == [10]:
            total += 5
        if w == [20]:
            total += 9
        if w == [40]:
            total += 17.5
        if w == [100]:
            total += 48
    return(w)
```

The goal for this assignment is figuring out how much the pizzas and other foods cost. I got stuck when inputting `cost_calculator([], ["ham", "anchovy"] , coupon=0.1)` as separate cell and find the cost of what is represented as one plain pizza, one pizza with ham and anchovy, with a 0.1% off coupon.

These links explain what exactly the assignment is
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiWB0.png
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZG0sm.png
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVbVM.png

Comment: `{[]:13}` is not a valid dictionary because lists can't be keys in dictionaries.

Comment: What happens, what exactly should happen? If there is an error message, show it completely as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking here, please show the output when your program fails

Answer (score 0):

Well, Lillian, there are several things you want to think about changing to make the code work, and to get the correct calculation.

One tricky part of that exercise is the ability to pass multiple, but unknown number of pizzas, to the cost calculator. My approach to that is to use the `*args` method to pass several pizzas in the way specified in the problem statement.

A few other points...

- you want to return the total from each of the individual calculator functions
- you want to treat toppings (like ham) as strings in the pizza calculator if statements
- well, and a few other things.

You can try this example code that modified several things from your original attempt

```py
def cost_calculator(*pizzas, drinks=None, wings=None, coupon=None):
    receipt = 0

    receipt += pizza_calc(pizzas)

    if drinks is not None:
        receipt += drinks_calc(drinks)
    if wings is not None:
        receipt += wings_calc(wings)

    tax = receipt * 0.0625
    discount = receipt * coupon
    receipt = receipt - discount + tax
    receipt = round(receipt, 2)

    return(receipt)

def pizza_calc(pizzas):
    total = 13 * len(pizzas)
    if len(pizzas):
        for p in pizzas:
            if 'pepperoni' in p:
                total += 1
            if 'mushroom' in p:
                total += 0.5
            if 'olive' in p:
                total += 0.5
            if 'anchovy' in p:
                total += 2
            if 'ham' in p:
                total += 1.5
    return(total)

def drinks_calc(drinks):
    total = 0.0
    for d in drinks:
        if d == "small":
            total += 2
        if d == "medium":
            total += 3
        if d == "large":
            total += 3.5
        if d == "tub":
            total += 3.75
    return(total)

def wings_calc(wings):
    total = 0.0
    for w in wings:
        if w == [10]:
            total += 5
        if w == [20]:
            total += 9
        if w == [40]:
            total += 17.5
        if w == [100]:
            total += 48
    return(total)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    p = ["ham", "anchovy"]
    drinks = ["small"]
    wings = []
    coupon = []

    total_bill = cost_calculator([], ["ham", "anchovy"], drinks = ["tub", "tub"], coupon = 0.1)

    print(total_bill)
```

Comment: Apparently, I need at least 2k reputation to review suggested edits, and the system is requesting that I review the edit. well, guess I cannot do that. So, I if someone can approve it, please do so.